# C# Debugging an Action

Tags: c#, debugging, xbehave.net

I have a .net core w/ .Net Framework project with a respective Test project. I'm using the [xBehave](http://xbehave.github.io/) xunit extension for unit testing. xBehave allows you to write what looks like a string extension that takes an Action.

```c#
public void Should_Create_Request()
 {
     "Given a Create OrderCommand Request"
                    .x(() => _orderCommand = Create());
 }
```

When debugging  this unit test, if I set a breakpoint in the Create method, the breakpoint never gets hit. The tests run successful, however I need to be able to step into code contained within the expression body.

Comment: never used xBehave. But break point wont get hit when you run unit tests

Comment: When you open Visual Studio Test Explorer, and right click a test you get a debug option that should allow you to hit breakpoints in the code that is being tested.

Comment: @MikeLunn did you ever get this working? It should be possible to hit breakpoints inside the body of a step. I do this regularly. I imagine that the problem lies somewhere in the config of your test runner.

Comment: @AdamRalph I'd have to circle back and try again. As much as I liked xBehave, I ended up not using it because of the issue I was having.